# Bad pointer when using malloc?

Tags: pointers, char, malloc, strlen

I'm trying the following:

```
int length = strlen(input)+1;
char * toCrypt = (char*)malloc(length);
```

Where input is some string. Whats strange is that sometimes this does work, and sometimes toCrypt gives a bad pointer... Solutions?

Comment: Does anything jump out at you if you compile with `-Wall`?

Comment: Could it be a wide-char problem, so that char is not in fact 1 byte, but 2?

`int length = strlen(input)+sizeof(char);`